# How to dynamically assign hash with $1, $2, $3

Tags: regex, perl, eval

I want to dynamically create a `%detail` hash, without using an `eval` statement.
This code is working fine with an `eval` statement, but is there any better way to perform this without using `eval`?

```
my @input=('INFO: Vikram 32 2012','SAL: 12000$','ADDRESS: 54, junk, JUNK');

my %matching_hash= (
                    qr/^INFO:\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)/ =>['name','age','joining'],
                    qr/^SAL:\s*(\S+)/ => ['salary'],
                    qr/ADDRESS:\s*(.*)/ =>['address']
                    );
my %detail;
while(my ($regex, $array) = each(%matching_hash)) {
    foreach (@input){
        if(/$regex/) {
            for(my $i=0;$i<=$#$array; $i++) {
                $j=$i+1;
                eval '$detail{$array->[$i]} = $$j';
            }
        }
    }
}
use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper(\%detail);
++++++++++++++

$VAR1 = {
          'name' => 'Vikram',
          'address' => '54, junk, JUNK',
          'age' => '32',
          'joining' => '2012',
          'salary' => '12000$'
        };
```

Comment: I don't think your eval statement will work if you `use strict` (I had to remove it from my test to get the desired output).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the for loop:

```
for(my $i=0;$i<=$#$array; $i++) {
    $j=$i+1;
    eval '$detail{$array->[$i]} = $$j';
}
```

by:

```
@detail{@{$array}} = ($_ =~ $regex);
```

Answer (score 14):

Relevant part:

```
if(my @m = /$regex/) {
  for(my $i=0;$i<=$#$array; $i++) {
      $detail{$array->[$i]} = $m[$i];              
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use lastest version of Perl, see to this notation `(?<name>...)` in regexp [perlre docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) It's more clear then using $1, $2, $3 etc.

**SCRIPT**

```
use v5.14;
use Data::Dumper;

my @inputs = ( 'INFO: Vikram 32 2012', 'SAL: 12000$','ADDRESS: 54, junk, JUNK' );

my %matching_hash= (
    qr/^INFO:\s*(?<name>\S+)\s+(?<age>\S+)\s+(?<joining>\S+)/ => [ 'name', 'age', 'joining' ],
    qr/^SAL:\s*(?<salary>\S+)/                                => [ 'salary' ],
    qr/ADDRESS:\s*(?<address>.*)/                             => [ 'address' ],
);

my %detail;
while (my ($regex, $array) = each %matching_hash ) {

    INPUT:
    foreach my $input ( @inputs ) {

        next INPUT if not $input =~ m{$regex};

        for my $name ( @$array ) {
            $detail{$name} = $+{$name};
        }
    }
}

say Dumper( \%detail);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'name'    => 'Vikram',
          'address' => '54, junk, JUNK',
          'age'     => '32',
          'joining' => '2012',
          'salary'  => '12000$'
        };
```

Comment: He shouldn't need the mapped arrays if he's going to use named matches just `@detail{ keys %+ } = values %+ if $input =~ m{$regex};` or even `%detail = %+ if $input =~ m{$regex};`. Then you could put the regexes into a structure that is much more fitting for iteration, a list/array. +1 for what I would have suggested.

Comment: `%detail = %+ if $input =~ m{$regex};` wouldn't work, it throws away what is already in `%detail`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the two arrays `@LAST_MATCH_START` and `@LAST_MATCH_END` (see `perldoc perlvar`) together with `substr` instead of `$1, $2...`. Something similar to

```
$detail{ $array->[$i] } = substr $_, $LAST_MATCH_START[$j], $LAST_MATCH_END[$j] - $LAST_MATCH_START[$j];
```

Comment: Agreed, except for the `English`.

Answer (score 1):

Using [named capture groups](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28%3f%27NAME%27pattern%29), you can eliminate the need for `%matching_hash` to be a hash. While at the same time eliminating the need to use the number variables, or assigning the result of the match in an array. This is because it will store the relevant information into `%+`.

```
use 5.10.1;

my @match = (
  qr'^INFO:\s*(?<name>\S+)\s+(?<age>\S+)\s+(?<joining>\S+)',
  qr'^SAL:\s*(?<salary>\S+)',
  qr'ADDRESS:\s*(?<address>.*)',
);

sub get_details{
  my %detail;

  for my $input ( @_ ) {
    for my $match ( @match ){
      next unless $input =~ $match;
      @detail{keys %+} = values %+;
      last;
    }
  }

  return \%detail;
}

use Data::Dumper;
my @inputs = ( 'INFO: Vikram 32 2012', 'SAL: 12000$','ADDRESS: 54, junk, JUNK' );
say Dumper get_details @inputs
```

It can get even simpler if you combine your `qr`'s into one.

```
use 5.10.1;

my $match= qr"
    ^INFO:   \s* (?<name>\S+) \s+ (?<age>\S+) \s+ (?<joining>\S+)
  | ^SAL:    \s* (?<salary>\S+)
  | ADDRESS: \s* (?<address>.*)
"x;

sub get_details{
  my %detail;

  for my $input ( @_ ) {
    $input =~ $match;
    @detail{keys %+} = values %+;
  }

  return \%detail;
}

use Data::Dumper;
my @inputs = ( 'INFO: Vikram 32 2012', 'SAL: 12000$','ADDRESS: 54, junk, JUNK' );
say Dumper get_details @inputs
```